# Populate span tag with jquery, using info only available within foreach loop when buttons are rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to MVC, so I am struggling a bit.  In the world of Web Forms, this is simple for me.  But after spending nearly a full day on this, I am throwing in the towel and asking for help.

I have MVC view where I am rendering a button within each iteration of foreach loop.  Within each iteration, I need to capture a color name and color id from my View Model, and use that info to populate a separate span tag outside of the looping buttons area.  I've tried a simple call to a javascript function using the onhover attribute, but that doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why.

Here is my code.  Thank you very much for any assistance!

```
<script>
  function updateColorName(colorName, colorId) {
        alert("in");
        document.getElementById("colorNameId").textContent = colorName + " ("                + colorId + ")";
  }
</script>

<div class="prod-desc">
  <div class="small-title">color: <span id="colorNameId" class="small-title">     </span>
    </div>
        <ul class="swatches list-inline list-unstyled">
            @foreach (var c in Model.MainProduct.FeaturedColors)
            {
                <li>
                    <button id="colorSwatch" 
                            type="submit"
                            class="swatch selected"                            
                            formaction=...
                            formmethod="post"                            
                            onhover='updateColorName(@c.ProductColorName, @c.ProductColorID);'>
                    </button>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: onmouseover or onclick.. why onhover?

Comment: It was one of many I tried, along with onmouseover, onmouseenter, onmouseleave.  None of them are getting me inside of the javascript function.

Comment: maybe help https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/ayeusn88/

Comment: It turns out that the reason the javascript function was not being called was because i did not have quotes around c.ProductColorName and c.ProductColorID.  I'm not completely sure why, since they are variables and not literals, but it does work now, so duly noted for future reference.  Thank you for your example Leo - it was that example that alerted me to not having the quotes.

Comment: happy that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onmouseover` event

```
onmouseover ="updateColorName('@c.ProductColorName', '@c.ProductColorId');"
```

Also the js function should update the `innerText`

```
function updateColorName(colorName, colorId) {
    document.getElementById("colorNameId").innerText = colorName + " ("+ colorId + ")";
}
```

Also you need to remove the hard coding of id from the loop. Duplicate Id values are invalid.

If you have jQuery included in the page, you can do this with an unobutrusive javascript way, which IMHO is more clean. In this approach, you can keep the product name and id in html5 data attributes. Add a css class to your button which we will later use to wire up the hover event.

```
@foreach (var c in Model.MainProduct.FeaturedColors)
{
    <li>
        <button type="submit"
                class="swatch selected hoveable"                            
                data-name="@c.ProductColorName"
                data-id="@c.ProductColorId">@c.ProductColorName
        </button>
    </li>
}
```

And now wire up the hover event

```
$(function() {

    $("button.hoveable").hover(function() {
        var name = $(this).data("name");
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var t = name + "(" + id + ")";
        $("#colorNameId").text(t);
    });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/xipiked/1/edit?html,css,js,output) is a working jsfiddle for your reference

Comment: Thank you so much for quick answer.  I forgot to mention that i had tried onmouseover, onmouseenter, and onmouseleave, but none of them are getting me inside of my javascript function.  My "alert" message isn't activating, and the text inside of the span isn't updating.  Once I am able to get inside of the JavaScript function, I should be ok.  Any idea why I can't get into the JavaScript function?

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle and compare it with your code http://jsbin.com/xipiked/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thank you Shyju.  I will try this out after lunch and a meeting, then let you know how it turns out.  I am not getting any script errors in the page.

Comment: It turns out that the reason the javascript function was not being called was because i did not have quotes around c.ProductColorName and c.ProductColorID. I'm not completely sure why, since they are variables and not literals, but it does work now, so duly noted for future reference.  Due to time constraints, I just kept my code as is (after adding the missing quotes), but your example looks like a great way of doing it and it is something i will attempt in the future.

Comment: yes. you need to use single or double quotes .If not, js will think those are variables and will throw a `node defined` exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code,

Set the name attribute of button inside `foreach` loop as,

```
<button id="colorSwatch" 
      type="submit"
      class="swatch selected"                                                     
      name="@c.ProductColorName&@c.ProductColorId"
      formmethod="post"...></button>
```

Then use the below code,

```
//Select all buttons with class swatch and selected
var buttonLink = document.querySelectorAll('button.swatch.selected');

//Iterate through each button and add an event listener for mouseover event
for (var i = 0; i < buttonLink.length; i++) {
    buttonLink[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {

        //Get the name of button and split at &
        var element= this.getAttribute('name').split('&');

        //you can do the functionality here itself
        document.getElementById("colorNameId").textContent = element[0] + " ("                + element[1] + ")";

        //or you can call the function
        //updateColorName(element[0],element[1]);
    });
}
```